# Audit what version of Remote Desktop users are using

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services, audit

we're trying to find out if there's any specific way to audit what version of remote desktop users are connecting with to a terminal server. You can find the version number manually by right clicking on the mstsc.exe bar at the top and selecting 'About', but in terms of a large company that has hundreds of users connecting this simply isn't feasible.

We want to find out exactly what version they're connecting with in the form of a log or some way that we can see them all in one place, the reason being that some users are experiencing lag and stuttering on their sessions, and we want to find out if the specific users affected are on the same version of Remote Desktop or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info in a powershell script using the [Cassia library](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/scriptfanatic/2010/02/22/psterminalservices-powershell-module-for-terminal-services/).

Just found out that MVP Francois-Xavier Cat started building something based on Cassia to [replace the tsadmin](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/10/powershell-gui-lazyts-terminal-services.html) - I have dreamed about this for a couple of years now...
Anyway, you'll probably need to customize it for your needs.